# Accessing to process data from programming language

Tags: process

I know this is kinda an odd question but I am not sure how to investigate further in google, perhaps soemone can help me out.

So I was playing League of Legends an noticed that there are some programs like "porofessor" or "Blitz" that can access to the client information in real time and show stadistics and stuff.

I am really curious on how to do that, if anyone knows what people use to do that, for example accessing to client masteries.

I've found a github project called "lolMimic" that emulates league client from the phone and select champions in the computer, what I am looking for is the link between the computer and the league of legends client.

Heres the project if anyone can help

https://github.com/molenzwiebel/mimic

Thanks a lot and sorry for the odd question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found how is done. Basically League of legends client when is executed sets up an Http server in a random port of your machine, if you find the process of the client you can find the port where the http server is executing and communicate with the client.